# Roman to int conversion problem gives an string index out of range error

Tags: python

I have a simple task to convert **roman to int**. this is the code I have been trying.

```
def romanToInt(s):
    """
    :type s: str
    :rtype: int
    """
    j=0
    print(len(s))
    for i in range(len(s)):
        k=s[i]
        l=i+1
        if s[i]=="I":
            if s[l]=="V":
                j+=4
            elif s[l]=="X":
                j+=9
        elif s[i]=="X":
            if s[l]=="L":
                j+=40
            elif s[l]=="C":
                j+=90
        elif s[i]=="C":
            if s[l]=="D":
                j+=400
            elif s[l]=="M":
                j+=900
        else:
            match k :
                case "I":
                    j+=1
                case "V":
                    j+=5
                case "X":
                    j+=10
                case "L":
                    j+=50
                case "C":
                    j+=100
                case "D":
                    j+=500
                case "M":
                    j+=1000
    return j

a=input("Enter number")
b=romanToInt(a)
print(b)
```

this code gives this error .

```
Enter numberIII
3
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\admin\Desktop\Dekstop Folder\pycharm\python\Leetcode\Roman to int.py", line 46, in <module>
    b=romanToInt(a)
      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\admin\Desktop\Dekstop Folder\pycharm\python\Leetcode\Roman to int.py", line 13, in romanToInt
    if s[l]=="V":
       ~^^^
IndexError: string index out of range

Process finished with exit code 1
```

I dont know why it says String index out of range.

I tried printing the length and it is in the range but i dont know why it does not work. please help.

Comment: When `i` is the last index, `l = i + 1` makes `l` outside the range of indexes.

Comment: Only do the parts that check the next character when `l < len(s)-1`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's often better to iterate over elements rather than the index to avoid some `IndexError`. `zip` can help you iterate over both the current character and the next one.

Another way to do it:

```
table = {'I': 1, 'V': 5, 'X': 10, 'L': 50, 'C': 100, 'D': 500, 'M': 1000}

def roman_to_int(s):
    num = 0
    for c1, c2 in zip(s, s[1:]):
        v1, v2 = table[c1], table[c2]
        num += v1 if v1 >= v2 else -v1
    return num + v2  # don't forget to add the last element
```

Usage:

```
>>> roman_to_int('IX')
9

>>> roman_to_int('VII')
7
```

Note: this code doesn't check the validity of the roman numerals (VIIIII = 10)

Comment: What is *roman*? Also, IX == 9.

Comment: @DarkKnight. Thanks. Bad copy/paste. I fixed my answer.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments, your problem comes when `i` reaches `len(s)-1`, meaning `l=i+1` is one past the end of the string.

Instead of using `s[l]`, you could use a slice of `s[l:l+1]`.  This will return an empty string when `l` is out of bounds instead of generating an error.

Answer (score 0):

**TL;DR**: Use the `roman.toRoman('XVII')` function from the `roman`package, found on pypi, to do this quickly and painlessly.

As suggested in the comment, the `1=i+1` will force the check on the last `I` to go outside range of the provided string.

##### Solutions:

1. The way you are implementing this is very tedious and repetitive. For this reason, I will not try to fix the "index out of range" error with repetitive `if` statements.
2. Simply use a python package called [roman](https://pypi.org/project/roman/) that does this for you in one line:

   ```
      import roman
      a = input("Enter number: ")
      b = roman.toRoman(a)
      print(b)
   ```

Comment: I believe OP is trying to implement the logic themselves, without using an existing Roman Numerals package.